# Работа с очередями и ООП (C++)

Tags: c++, ооп, очередь

Дан текстовый файл с изображением целых чисел, которые необходимо переписать в очередь Qu1. В очередь Qu2 сначала записать числа палиндромы, затем числа, сумма цифр которых нечетная, остальные числа записать в выходной файл. Создать программу с применением методов ООП.

Сделал что смог, но появилось много ошибок... Прошу вашей помощи!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

unsigned getReverse(unsigned n) {
    unsigned r = n % 10;
    while (n /= 10) {
        r = r * 10 + n % 10;
    }
    return r;
}
bool isPalindrom(const unsigned n) {
    return n == getReverse(n);
}

class cQueue
{
protected:
    queue<int> p_;
public:
    void IO();

    void Del()
    {
        while (!p_.empty())
        {
            p_.pop();
        }
    };
};

void cQueue::IO()
{
    ifstream ifile("text.txt");
    ofstream ofile("output.txt", ios::trunc);

    queue<int> qu1 = p_;
    for_each(istream_iterator<int>(ifile), istream_iterator<int>(), [&qu1](int n)
    {
        qu1.push(n);
    });

    cout << "Number of items in the queue: " << qu1.size() << endl;
    while (!qu1.empty())
    {
        cout << "\nHere they are: " << qu1.front() << '\n';
    }

    queue<int> qu2;
    copy_if(queue<int>(qu1), queue<int>(), queue<int>(qu2), [&qu1](int n) -> bool
    {
        if (isPalindrom(n)) {
            return n;
        }
        else if (n) {
            // Сумма нечетных чисел ?
        }
        else
        {
            // В выходной файл ?
        }
    });

    cout << "Number of items in the queue: " << qu2.size() << endl;
    while (!qu2.empty())
    {
        cout << "\nHere they are: " << qu2.front() << '\n';
    }
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Demo Queue OOP" << endl;

    cQueue queue;
    queue.IO();
    cout << endl;
    queue.Del();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> Ошибка    C2675   унарный "++":
>   "std::queue>>" не определяет
>   этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному
>   оператору \algorithm  594
>
> Ошибка    C2100   недопустимое косвенное обращение \algorithm 596
>
> Ошибка    C2100   недопустимое косвенное обращение \algorithm 598
>
> Ошибка    C2675   унарный "++":
>   "std::queue>>" не определяет
>   этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному
>   оператору \algorithm  599
>
> Ошибка    C4996   'std::copy_if::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to
>   'std::copy_if' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies
>   on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable
>   this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how
>   to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' \algorithm 589

Comment: Так а вы пишите постепенно, разбираясь с ошибками по мере появления.

Comment: @VTT все ошибки происходят из за `copy_if(...)`

Comment: Ну так первые три параметра должны быть итераторами. В справочник стоит иногда заглядывать.

Comment: очередь не поддерживает итераторов, и не является итератором(как у вас в коде).  Обходиться нужно без STL  альгоритмов

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
struct IsPoli {
    bool operator()(const int i)
    {
        string s = to_string(i), t = s;
        std::reverse(t.begin(), t.end());
        return  s == t;
    }
};
struct CheckSum {
    bool operator()(int n)
    {
        int count{};
        while(n) {
            if(n & 1) ++count;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return (count & 1);
    }
};
int main()
{    
    ifstream ifile("text.txt");
    ofstream ofile("output.txt");
    queue<int> Qu1, Qu2;
    for_each(istream_iterator<int>(ifile), istream_iterator<int>(),
             [&](const int& i) { Qu1.push(i);});
    IsPoli p;
    CheckSum cmp;
    int k{};
    vector<int> v;
    while(!Qu1.empty()) {
        k = Qu1.front();
        if (!p(k) && !cmp(k))
            ofile << k << ' ';
        else if (p(k)){
            Qu2.push(k);
        } else
            v.emplace_back(k);
        Qu1.pop();
    }
    for (const int& i :v)
        Qu2.push(i);
    // дальше можно показать содержимое второй очереди
    while(!Qu2.empty()) {
        cout << endl << Qu2.front();
        Qu2.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста как работает CheckSum? Не совсем понял...

Comment: n & 1 дает true если первый бит  есть 1, т.е. если  n есть нечетное число. count  хранит число нечетных чисел(можно вместо этого выражения написать n%2), и если их количество нечетное, то и сумма этих чисел будет нечетной...  Все ясно?.. Код в целом еще можно оптимизировать( я его написал не долго думая)

Comment: Да, все спасибо, понял!

Answer (score 0):

Свой `copy_if` для очередей сделать надо. Или не пользоваться очередями.

```
std::queue<int> input;
...
std::queue<int> result;
std::queue<int> inputcopy(input);
while(not input_copy.empty()){
  if(...) result.push(input_copy.front());
  input_copy.pop();}
```